# Typo3 update 9.5.16 Page tree error for non admin users

Tags: typo3

After the update from typo3 9.5.15 to 9.5.16, a backend-user does not see the page tree, instead, there is a message:

"Page tree error" "Got unexpected response from the server. Please check logs for details." /
Seitenbaumfehler  "Unerwartete Antwort vom Server erhalten. Bitte überprüfen Sie die Protokolle für mehr Details."

I updated a copy of the system to 10.4.1 - the same problem.

Admins are not affected.

No error is shown in the log-file.

I changed the debug settings to Debug[Active] and no errors are shown.

When I go back to 9.5.15 the problem disappears.

**This problem was fixed with the update to 9.5.17 or 10.4.2!**

Comment: Could it be this issue? https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is this bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91221
There is already a solution available and a patch is coming in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the hints! (Bug #91221):
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91221

I changed the two php-files mentioned there:https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/64346

The pagetree works fine again
(but if you create an user with a direct mountpoint - not from groups - the problem  still exists).