# Typo3 backend page tree error in version 10.4.9

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

In my relatively new TYPO3 installation (Version 10.4.9) I wanted to add some backend users that do not have admin rights. When I login as a recently created backend user that has no admin rights and click on "pages" the following error occurs:

"Page tree error" "Got unexpected response from the server. Please check logs for details." / Seitenbaumfehler "Unerwartete Antwort vom Server erhalten. Bitte überprüfen Sie die Protokolle für mehr Details."

In the protocol of TYPO3 there are no errors documented. When I give the user admin rights the page tree shows up with no error. Clearing caches does not help. I found out that there was the same error in an earlier version but it should have been fixed in the 10er version:

[Typo3 update 9.5.16 Page tree error for non admin users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578859/typo3-update-9-5-16-page-tree-error-for-non-admin-users)

Has anyone a suggestion how I could solve that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [DB mount](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/master/en-us/UserManagement/GroupPermissions/Index.html#db-mounts) to the user or the backend user group. And you need to set proper [access rights](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/master/en-us/UserManagement/PagePermissions/Index.html) to the page tree via the TYPO3 backend module System => Access.